# Using values from an insert in a trigger

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm using a trigger that triggers AFTER INSERT, when the user inserts data into the the table i want to be able to use the information that was just inserted into the table in my trigger.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the special variable `new` to get the data for the new added row(s), as described in the manual at [13.1.22 CREATE TRIGGER Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html)

> Within the trigger body, you can refer to columns in the subject table (the table associated with the trigger) by using the aliases `OLD` and `NEW`. `OLD.col_name` refers to a column of an existing row before it is updated or deleted. `NEW.col_name` refers to the column of a new row to be inserted or an existing row after it is updated.

Comment: Yeah, i totally glossed over that, this is my bad and i should not have missed this.